# How to install all imports at once?

Tags: python

Instead of having to run a python script and then get errors saying `"ImportError: No module named aaa"` because that module isn't installed in my system and then install it and then run the script again, and then maybe get the same kind of error for another module, is there any way to discover which modules aren't installed in my system and install them all at once if there're ones that aren't installed yet and which are required for the script?

Comment: For this purpose you should have a `requirements.txt` in your project: https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html

Comment: @KlausD. what if it's a third-party project and it doesn't have the file requirements?

Answer (score 7):

Add all your imports in a single txt file, say `requirements.txt` and every time you run your program on a new system, just do a

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Most Code editor's like Pycharm do this for you on the first run.
You can do a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get all the installed/required packages.

Comment: 1) what if it was `from module1.module2 import Class3`?

Comment: 2) what if the name of module was different from its name in pip?

Comment: 1.`pip freeze` would give you `module1`, provided module1 isn't some module that you have written, and if you have the whole module, the `Class3` import will work.

Comment: 2. I am not sure if you are referring to modules created by yourself here. If  you have imported a module as 'import request as r`, then pip freeze would give you `request` module, which would work even for `import request as r`

Comment: You should read the [link](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html) provided by @KlausD, it will answer most of your questions. And if no, Google is your friend.